# Drupal 7 Views: How to filter content by user->mail-global variable?

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-views, global

currently i am building a website where every logged in user shall have access to a "my gallery-site" where the galleries are listed, which match a contet-field: "usermail".
The System is the current drupal 7 + views module.

My thought was to have something like a filter:

```
is equal to = $user->mail
```

to interact with the user globals of php. Is there such a possibility ?

Comment: Why don't you use author id? (that one is available in views), it would also allow more flexibility later if you would want to add a block to user pages (you can then use a contextual filter to get the id of the userpage you are looking at)

Comment: For better understanding: the administrator creates galleries for different users, and when a registered user logs in there shall be a menu link to a site, where he sees all galleries, assigned to his name, account or whatever.

Comment: Then your administrator might want to use entity reference (http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to reference users from within galleries. In views you can use the backward reference to find galleries connected to the current user.

Comment: Sounds interesting, any advice how to use this module?

Comment: Add the reference field to your content type, then on gallery creation (or edit) add one or multiple some users.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes i already found this step and i can enter these references, but i also had a field before named "usermail" now that i have this field i need the views module to be able to filter with this criteria, so the important step i want to take is to understand how i can access this reference in the views config to say: "when reference is equal to JON DOE show this gallery"

Comment: so "John Doe" has to be dynamic so that every logged in user only sees his galleries marked for him.

Comment: You will need to use a contextual filter, select the reference field, then choose to provide a default value and pick id of logged in user.

Comment: Yes i get that, but then i have the UID to compare not the mail address. This would work out if i would assign the UID to every gallery i create. But when i have 100 users or more, i would have to look up all the IDs when i create a gallery therefore i want to work with the E-Mail.Address or the User Name this would also work .

Comment: Therefor I recommended reference, that will attach uid to galleries.  (By selecting username) There is no simple solution for this with email. (sorry for the confusion, I thought you understood the switch)

Comment: Damn ^^ now i got it. It´s working. Dropdown Userswitch + Reference UID, thank u very much, in the end not much work, but long way to get into this whole abstract reference system. Especially cause i found no real documentary for this module.

Comment: Great! You might want to answer your question with more detailed steps, then you can report this post and request removal of comments, so we can keep SO clean ;)